# How to Identify a Weekend and Subtract it Automatically From my Time Differences in R

Tags: r, difftime

I am writing a code that uses two vectors of timestamps to give me the time needed for a specific process (simply difftime).

But on weekends the time should be on halt. So if a product comes in, on a Friday and leaves on a Tuesday, I have to subtract the weekend-time.
So i need a possibility to identify when a products process time goes through a weekend, the weekend gets subtracted from the time difference automatically.

The identification of these products is more the problem than the subtraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `is.weekend` from `chron` package.

```
days<-seq.Date(as.Date("01-01-2017",format= "%d-%m-%Y"),as.Date("01-04-2017",format= "%d-%m-%Y"),by = "days")   
library(chron)  
  days[is.weekend(days)]
  [1] "2017-01-01" "2017-01-07" "2017-01-08" "2017-01-14" "2017-01-15" "2017-01-21" "2017-01-22"
  [8] "2017-01-28" "2017-01-29" "2017-02-04" "2017-02-05" "2017-02-11" "2017-02-12" "2017-02-18"
 [15] "2017-02-19" "2017-02-25" "2017-02-26" "2017-03-04" "2017-03-05" "2017-03-11" "2017-03-12"
 [22] "2017-03-18" "2017-03-19" "2017-03-25" "2017-03-26" "2017-04-01"

  weekdays.Date(days[is.weekend(days)])
  [1] "Sunday"   "Saturday" "Sunday"   "Saturday" "Sunday"   "Saturday" "Sunday"   "Saturday"
  [9] "Sunday"   "Saturday" "Sunday"   "Saturday" "Sunday"   "Saturday" "Sunday"   "Saturday"
 [17] "Sunday"   "Saturday" "Sunday"   "Saturday" "Sunday"   "Saturday" "Sunday"   "Saturday"
 [25] "Sunday"   "Saturday"
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `weekdays` might be of help here:

```
weekdays(as.Date("2018-07-30"))
# [1] "monday"
```

So if you pass a vector of dates object, you'll be able to id the saturdays and sundays.

For example:

```
which(weekdays(as.Date(c("2018-07-30", "2018-07-29", "2018-07-28", "2018-07-27"))) %in% c("saturday", "sunday"))
[1] 2 3
```